# How can I get a list of object and then convert them to a page?

Tags: java, spring-boot, pagination

I have a Product class

```
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class Product extends AbsEntity {

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String name;

    @Length(max = 500)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String description;

    private double price;//Evaluated in the $

    @OneToOne
    private Category category;

    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private User owner;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Attachment attachment;
}
```

and repository:

```
@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, UUID> {

    
    boolean existsByNameAndOwner(String name, User owner);

    List<Product> findAllByCategoryName(String categoryName);

    List<Product> findAllByOwnerId(UUID owner_id);
}
```

When I try to get them and then page:

```
public HttpEntity<?> getProducts(int pageNum, int pageSize) {

    Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(pageNum, pageSize);

    List<ProductDto> productDtoList = 
productRepository.findAll().stream().map(helperClass::mapProductToProductDto).
collect(Collectors.toList());

    Page<ProductDto> products = new PageImpl<>(productDtoList, pageable, productDtoList.size());

    return ResponseEntity.ok(products);
}
```

and my helperClass method :

```
public ProductDto mapProductToProductDto(Product product) {

    ProductDto productDto = new ProductDto();

    productDto.setName(product.getName());
    productDto.setPicture(product.getAttachment().getContent());
    productDto.setPrice(product.getPrice());
    productDto.setDescription(product.getDescription());
    productDto.setOwnerName(product.getOwner().getFullName());
    productDto.setCategoryName(product.getCategory().getName());
    productDto.setAddedDate(product.getCreatedAt());

    return productDto;
}
```

It is not returning necessary page but returning me all products in a single page. Is there a way to receive a list of object and then turn them ito a page?? What is a problem here?

Comment: See https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/PagingAndSortingRepository.html

Answer (score 0):

Pass the [`Pageable`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Pageable.html) to [`findAll`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/PagingAndSortingRepository.html#findAll(org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)):

```java
Page<Product> page = productRepository.findAll(pageable);
List<ProductDto> productList = page.getContent().stream()
   .map(helperClass::mapProductToProductDto).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

To return a Pageable way, you can modify your findAll method as this

> Page productPage = productRepository.findAll(pageable);

you can modify the code as follows:

```
public HttpEntity<?> getProducts(int pageNum, int pageSize) {

Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(pageNum, pageSize);

Page<Product> productPage = productRepository.findAll(pageable);
List<ProductDto> productDtoList = productPage.getContent().stream()
        .map(helperClass::mapProductToProductDto)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

Page<ProductDto> productDtoPage = new PageImpl<>(productDtoList, pageable, productPage.getTotalElements());

return ResponseEntity.ok(productDtoPage);
}
```